# LWJGL - Color is changing texture

Tags: java, rendering, lwjgl

I am trying to draw a texture and then draw a red box over a certain portion of it to identify an area. However when I draw the red box and set the color using `glColor3f(255, 0, 0);` it gives the texture a whole red tint to it. I am assuming this is because I have this enabled:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

But this is necessary because the texture has transparent portions of it. How do I prevent the red tint from occuring?

**CODE**

```
public void render() {
    playerTexture.bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);
    glVertex2f((int)x, (int)y);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0);
    glVertex2f((int)(x + width), (int)y);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);
    glVertex2f((int)(x + width), (int)(y + height));
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f((int)x, (int)(y + height));
    glEnd();

    if(renderCollisionBox) {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(255, 0, 0);
        glVertex2f(collisionBox[0][0], collisionBox[0][1]);
        glVertex2f(collisionBox[1][0], collisionBox[1][1]);
        glVertex2f(collisionBox[2][0], collisionBox[2][1]);
        glVertex2f(collisionBox[3][0], collisionBox[3][1]);
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

**Picture**
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPsOa.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you would upload some images of what you mean.

Comment: @JimGarrison added a link